# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString replacing composites of longer words

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, string, nsstring

When using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`, it seems to replace words inside words. So for example,

```
The house was held together by...
```

replacing occurrences of 'the' with 'A' will result in

```
A house was held togeAr by...
```

How can I avoid this? I know I could add whitespace on either side of the word being replaced to ensure it's not part of a longer word, however this doesn't work in all cases, specifically where the word being replaced is the first or last word in the sentence (that is, when white space isn't on both sides).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an `NSRegularExpression` with the pattern `\bthe\b` where `\b` indicates a word boundary.

```
NSString *input = @"The house was held together by...";
NSString *string = @"the";
NSString *replacement = @"A";

NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\b%@\\b", string];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSString *result = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:input options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, input.length) withTemplate:replacement];

NSLog(@"%@", result);
// A house was held together by...
```

Comment: Wow, I literally can't thank you enough. So simple. Never heard of regular expressions before. Well, heard of them, had no idea what they were. This has solved a problem I've been stuck on for a while. I had all sorts of elaborate techniques to try and make it work...

Answer (score 1):

For more complex replacement operations, you can use `NSRegularExpression`. You could search for something like `(^| )the($| )` and replace matches.